# Shell-Script with multiple screen sessions does nothing

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, gnu-screen

I Have a Problem with the following Shell-Script which should start two screen sessions. When I execute it there is simply nothing happening. Does anybody have a clue why this is the case? My System is the newest raspbian.

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -Smd server node ./SensorService/bin/app.js
screen -Smd receiver python3 receiver.py
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try putting an ampersand to the end of the second and the third lines to put the jobs in the background.

```
#!/bin/sh
screen -Smd server node ./SensorService/bin/app.js &
screen -Smd receiver python3 receiver.py &
```

Comment: This worked! However I get the following error messages:  
: not foundrtup.sh: 2: startup.sh:  
: not foundrtup.sh: 3: startup.sh:

Comment: we don't see `foundrtup.sh` or `startup.sh` in the code you have posted! How can we reproduce your problem? Good luck.

Comment: I can't see foundrtup.sh either. startup.sh is the filename. Sorry for that.

Comment: These errors occured, because I used Windows line endings. Converted them to UNIX with Notepad++